# How to mimic template variable declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I have a basic type `Item<N>` which depends on an integer template parameter `N` and class `Data` which holds instances of `Item<N>` for several different `N`.

Here is an example:

```
template<unsigned N>
struct Item { ... }; // some template data type

struct Data
{
    std::set<Item<1>> items1;
    std::set<Item<2>> items2;
    std::set<Item<3>> items3;
    std::set<Item<4>> items4;
    std::set<Item<5>> items5;

    bool contains(const Item<1>& x) { return items1.find(x) != items1.end(); }
    bool contains(const Item<2>& x) { return items2.find(x) != items2.end(); }
    bool contains(const Item<3>& x) { return items3.find(x) != items3.end(); }
    bool contains(const Item<4>& x) { return items4.find(x) != items4.end(); }
    bool contains(const Item<5>& x) { return items5.find(x) != items5.end(); }
};
```

Now with several functions like `contains` there is a lot of code duplication. Is there a more elegant way to implement `Data`?

Comment: May be some kind of recursive definition in the range of N = [1..5]? I still try to understand your use case here: What are the conditions for `N` in relation to the instantiation rules for `Data`?

Comment: The design choices that led you to ask this question seem like poor ones. This code is *not* self-documenting, and as such is a maintenance hazard. Names are an important part of writing modern maintainable code - do not underestimate their value. I suggest searching for a more elegant design. Numeric templates hardly seem appropriate for Items.

Comment: @Mark: I *am* looking for a more elegant design, hence the question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, e.g., store a suitable `std::tuple<...>` and have your `contain()` function be a template, e.g.:

```
template <int... I>
struct DataImpl {
    std::tuple<std::set<Item<I>>...> data;
    template <int J>
    bool contains(Item<J> const& x) {
        return std::get<J-1>(data).find(x) != std::get<J-1>(data).end();
    }
};
using Data = DataImpl<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>;
```

Comment: Is this also going to work for DataImpl<2,1,3,4,5> ?

Comment: @Danvil: no, that will give you errors on access: the sequence isn't reorder and the position in the tuple is derived from the deduced type. If you want to use arbitrary orders you'll need to sort/fill the integer sequence which can be done but is probably not a trival exercise.

Comment: @Danvil: Not as written since `std::get<N>(data)` returns the Nth element of `std::tuple`, with C++1y, we may use `std::get<std::set<Item<J - 1>>>(data)`

Comment: @Jarod42: good point. A function like the type based `get<...>()` could be written in C++11, too. Also not quite trivial, I think, but easier than sorting the the values.

Comment: To make it easier you can use C++1y `std::integer_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` so instantiation will look something like `template<int N> using Data = DataImpl<std::make_index_sequence<N>>; template class Data<5>;` `DataImpl` would have to be specialized for `std::integer_sequence` and you would also have to increase by one in the parameter pack: `tuple<set<Item<(Is + 1)...>>>`

Answer (score 3):

Following may help:

```
struct Data
{
    std::tuple<std::set<Item<1>>,
               std::set<Item<2>>,
               std::set<Item<3>>,
               std::set<Item<4>>,
               std::set<Item<5>>> items;

    template <int N>
    bool contains(const Item<N>& x) const {
        static_assert(0 < N && N < 6, "N out of range");
        return std::get<N - 1>(items).find(x) != std::get<N - 1>(items).end();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something with a "type list", like so:

```
template <unsigned int ...> struct Data;

template <> struct Data<> {};

template <unsigned int N, unsigned int ...Tail>
struct Data : Data<Tail...>
{
    std::set<Item<N>> item;
    bool contains(const Item<N> & x) const { return item.find(x) != item.end(); }
};
```

Usage:

```
Data<2, 8, 19> data;   // contains sets of Item<2>, Item<8> and Item<19>
```