# vector <template>, c++, class, adding to vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to create a class thats going to draw elements from a set of vectors (and also hold these vectors as containers inside the class), but i feel that when managing the vector having lots of functions like vectorOneAdd, vectorTwoAdd used in order to add elements to the vector is pointless. There must be a better way, thats why i am asking here, I heard you can use templates to do it, but i am not quite certain how. Assistance needed. Don't want to have lots of pointless code in.

Example of what I mean below:

```
class Cookie
{
std::vector<Chocolate> chocolateContainer;
std::vector<Sugar> sugarContainer;

void chocolateVectorAdd(Chocolate element);    // first function adding to one vector
void sugarVectorAdd(Sugar element);   // second function adding to another vector
}
```

Please use example code, thanks :)

Comment: If you have multiple container variables, you need multiple functions to add to them. There is no way to now which of the variables to pick from a type.

Comment: P.S As I am already being downvoted, I was searching for the answer but all I found was how to return 2 different types in a template.

Comment: What you *could* do, is make all contained types (like `Chocolate` and `Sugar` in your example) inherit from the same virtual base class, then you only need a single container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927455/how-to-mimic-template-variable-declaration/20927537#comment31422993_20927537

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> having lots of functions like vectorOneAdd, vectorTwoAdd used in order to add elements to the vector is pointless. There must be a better way

There is:

```
class Cookie {
    std::vector<Chocolate> chocolateContainer;
    std::vector<Sugar> sugarContainer;

private:
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>& get_vector(const T&); // not implemented but particularized

    // write one of these for each vector:
    template<>
    std::vector<Chocolate>& get_vector(const Chocolate&) { return chocolateVector; }
    template<>
    std::vector<Sugar>& get_vector(const Sugar&) { return sugarVector; }

public:
    template<typename T>
    void add(T element) {
        auto& v = get_vector(element);
        v.push_back(std::move(element));
    }
};
```

Comment: Personally I'd rather drop the unused parameter and write fully `get_vector<T>()`, but you got my +1.

Comment: You still have to make one `get_vector` function per container. It's just the public interface that's cleaner.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's the point: if you need a new function in the public interface (e.g. `count` for sugar and for chocolate) you can implement it on the same `get_vector` primitives, with a single (similarly template-d) implementation.

Comment: You could even sotre the vectors in a [boost::fusion::map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/map.html) then you would not need to implement a `get_vector` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Following will solve your problem (need C++11)

```
#if 1 // std::get<T>(tuple) is not in C++11

// Helper to retrieve index to be able to call std::get<N>(tuple)
template <typename T, typename ... Ts> struct get_index;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct get_index<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename Tail,  typename ... Ts>
struct get_index<T, Tail, Ts...> :
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + get_index<T, Ts...>::value> {};
#endif

template <typename ... Ts>
class Data
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void push_back(const T& x) { return getVector<T>().push_back(x); }

    template <typename T>
    std::size_t size() const { return getVector<T>().size(); }

private:
    template <typename T>
    const std::vector<T>& getVector() const { return std::get<get_index<T, Ts...>::value>(items); }

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T>& getVector() { return std::get<get_index<T, Ts...>::value>(items); }
private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> items;
};
```

Test it:

```
class A{};
class B{};

int main()
{
    Data<A, B> d;

    d.push_back(A());
    d.push_back(B());
    return 0;
}
```