# Adding additional vectors to a class

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Let me demonstrate my problem with an example.

Lets say I have a bunch of very simple structs, like this:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B
{
    float y;
    bool z;
};
```

And I have a class that stores these structs in vectors. It has a method for adding new batch of structs (there is always the same number of each struct), and it has a method for accessing each struct by its index. Something like this:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        void Create()
        {
            A a = {};
            B b = {};
            _vecA.push_back(a);
            _vecB.push_back(b);
        }

        A* GetA(unsigned int i)
        {
            return &_vecA[i];
        }

        B* GetB(unsigned int i)
        {
            return &_vecB[i];
        }

    private:
        std::vector<A> _vecA;
        std::vector<B> _vecB;
};
```

Now, the problem is that whenever I add another struct into the program I have to add bunch of stuff into that class. For example, if I add another struct (lets call it *C*), I have to add another vector, another push_back call, and create the *GetC()* method.

Now, my question is: Is there a better way to do that?

Here's one way I thought of doing it:

```
class ContainerBase
{
    public:
        ContainerBase(){};
        virtual ~ContainerBase(){};
        virtual void Add(){};
};

template <typename T>
class Container : public ContainerBase
{
    public:
            // Singleton
            static Container& Instance()
            {
                static Container instance;
                return instance;
            }

            void Add()
            {
                T t = {};
                _bag.push_back(t);
            }

            T* Get(unsigned int i)
            {
                return &_bag[i];
            }

        private:
            Container(){};
            ~Container(){};

            std::vector<T> _bag;
};

class Test
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void Register()
        {
            _containers.push_back(&Container<T>::Instance());
        }

        void Create()
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _containers.size(); i++)
                _containers[i]->Add();
        }

        template <typename T>
        T* Get(unsigned int i)
        {
            return Container<T>::Instance().Get(i);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<ContainerBase*> _containers;
};
```

I tried to solve it by creating a templated class *Container* for managing the vector of each type. As you can see, it involves using a singleton pattern to make sure that there's always a *Container* for the particular type of struct. The types of structs just need to be registered with the class using the *Register* method, so that *Test* knows which *Containers* it should add the new structs to, when the new batch is created. This solution is problematic because it introduces global state to the containers, and by doing that makes it impossible to create two instances of the *Test* class that don't share their vectors for a certain type of structs. If I don't make the containers singletons, than there is no way I could access them by type in the *Test*'s Get function, I would have to know which index in the _*containers* vector corresponds to what type of container.

I feel that there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vector <template>, c++, class, adding to vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971819/vector-template-c-class-adding-to-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving the problem.

I made a ContainerMapper class that has a map of different struct types (using the typeinfo to get the type), each type is mapped to a templated Container for that type.

```
std::map<const std::type_info*, ContainerBase*> _map;
```

I also keep a vector of all registered types so I can iterate over them if I need to.

```
std::vector<const std::type_info*> _types;
```

To register new types I call the *CointainerMapper*'s *Register()* method:

```
template <typename T>
void Register()
{
    _types.push_back(&typeid(T));
    _map[&typeid(T)] = new Container<T>;
}
```

And to access them I use:

```
template <typename T>
Container<T>* Get()
{
    return (Container<T>*)_map[&typeid(T)];
}
```

The container code is same as the one in the example in the question.

When I want to create another batch of structs I simply iterate over the registered types, get the mapped containers and call their Add() method.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _types.size(); i++)
    _map[_types[i]]->Add();
```

Using all this looks like this:

```
ContainerMapper m;
m.Register<A>();

m.Create();

// Get container
Container<A>* cA = m.Get<A>();
// Get first element
A* a = cA->Get(0);
// Set x member variable
a->x = 4;

// Or shorter way
m.Get<A>()->Get(0)->x = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

use a base class, make A,B and C derived from that base class, and keep a base class vector/vectors only. Its called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: That, or make the container class a template too, just like `vector` is.

Comment: I need to have separate vectors for each struct type. That is crucial for my program. Having only one vector would make it difficult to iterate through only one type of structs.

Comment: then keep one vector<baseClass> per type, maybe in a vector too, and so you could iterate on your one type of structs, or add a new type  fairly easily.

Comment: @WeaselFox How would I know then which vector<baseClass> is used for which type.

Comment: use an enum maybe... or any other way you want really, this kind of exceeds the limits of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be possible. I could make something like std::map<type, std::vector<baseClass>*> where type is an enum, but then implementing the Create method in the example in the question (adding a new batch of structs, one of each type) would be difficult. I realize it would have to iterate the map over every type and add a new element to the vector, but how would it know which type of element it should add. For example, if it's one type add an A element, if it's another type add B element, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Following will solve your problem (need C++11)

```
#if 1 // std::get<T>(tuple) is not in C++11

// Helper to retrieve index to be able to call std::get<N>(tuple)
template <typename T, typename ... Ts> struct get_index;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct get_index<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename Tail,  typename ... Ts>
struct get_index<T, Tail, Ts...> :
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + get_index<T, Ts...>::value> {};
#endif

template <typename ... Ts>
class Data
{
public:

    void Create() {
        int dummy[] = {0, (getVector<Ts>().emplace_back(), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // silent warning about unused variable
    }

    template <typename T>
    const T* Get(std::size_t i) const { return &getVector<T>()[i]; }
    template <typename T>
    T* Get(std::size_t i) { return &getVector<T>()[i]; }

private:
    template <typename T>
    const std::vector<T>& getVector() const { return std::get<get_index<T, Ts...>::value>(items); }

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T>& getVector() { return std::get<get_index<T, Ts...>::value>(items); }
private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> items;
};
```

Test it:

```
class A{};
class B{};

int main()
{
    Data<A, B> d;

    d.Create();
    const B* b = d.Get<B>(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a better solution. Although I don't really understand what is happening with the get_index. I'm going to have to study it a bit closer.

Comment: One side question, why are you returning T& in the Get methods instead of the pointer?

Comment: I prefer to return reference when possible. You may return pointer instead, if you want.

Comment: `get_index` is a meta-programmation to retrieve the index of type `T` in `T1, T2, T3, ..., TN`. because in C++11, `std::get<T>(tuple)` is not available (should be in C++1y).

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that the same types are packed together in memory? AAABBBCCC instead of ABCABCABC. Atleast I guess it's ABCABCABC currently That would improve  the cache coherency, since when I iterate, most of the time I do it over the same type.

Comment: @raster: It is possible (as done in [vector-template-c-class-adding-to-vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971819/vector-template-c-class-adding-to-vector)). The Create method is more complicated though... BTW edited.