# C++ template specialization from child type

Tags: c++

I have a class hierarchy like:

```
          A<int, int>
          / \
B<int,int>   C<int,int>
```

and a further class `Foo<int, int>` that has a list of these types its members. They cannot be combined into a single list of `A`s as i need to operate with them separately. Is there anyway (in C++98 only) to add a method that can correctly insert them into the correct container, such as:

```
template<int X, int Y>
class Foo
{
  std::vector< shared_ptr<B<int, int> > > mBs;
  std::vector< shared_ptr<C<int, int> > > mCs;

  template<template <int, int> class T>
  add_element
  {
     mBs.insert(shared_ptr<B<X, Y> >(new B<x, Y>()); if its a B
     mCs.insert(shared_ptr<C<X, Y> >(new C<x, Y>()); if its a C
  }
};
```

and do this in client code:

```
Foo bar;
bar.add_element<TypeDerivedFromB>();
bar.add_element<TypeDerivedFromC>();
```

I could have two separate functions named differently, but that makes the interface a bit nasty. Thanks

Comment: SFINAE on `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: Thanks, but can't use C++11 unfortunately.

Comment: Boost.TypeTraits [`is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) then. Need help with that?

Comment: Just write two overloads, one for each type.

Comment: awesome! I *should* be able to work it out from other SFINAE stuff on SO. Thanks again Bartek!

Comment: This begs the question: *and of what of a class derived from both* ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. good point. In this specific context, it should be disallowed to create a class derived from both.

Comment: Related to C++11 questions : [How to mimic template variable declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927455/how-to-mimic-template-variable-declaration/20927537#comment31422949_20927537) and [vector <template>, c++, class, adding to vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971819/vector-template-c-class-adding-to-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may help.
it uses SFINAE:

```
template<int X, int Y> class B{};
template<int X, int Y> class C{};

template<int X, int Y>
class Foo
{
  std::vector< std::shared_ptr<B<X, Y> > > mBs;
  std::vector< std::shared_ptr<C<X, Y> > > mCs;

public:
  template<template <int, int> class T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T<X, Y>, B<X, Y> >::value>::type
  add_element()
  {
    mBs.push_back(std::shared_ptr<B<X, Y> >(new B<X, Y>));
  }

  template<template <int, int> class T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T<X, Y>, C<X, Y> >::value>::type
  add_element()
  {
    mCs.push_back(std::shared_ptr<C<X, Y> >(new C<X, Y>));
  }

};
```

Not sure it is better than 2 methods with different name...